What was Bertrand Russell's take on the resolution of Russell's paradox?
Russell's paradox (circa 1903), as you have probably learned, is that if there is a set that is the set of all sets, then its subset consisting of [the set of all sets not members of themselves] can neither be a member of itself nor can it not be a member of itself — contradiction.
It led to a great focus on finding axiom systems for set theory that avoided such paradoxes.
The resolution most often quoted is the axiom system known as ZF (for Zermelo-Fraenkel), constructed in the 1920s. Often the Axiom of Choice is included, and it's then called ZFC for short.
In this case, there is such a thing as the collection of all sets, but it does not qualify as a set, so it is called a proper class.
In ZFC there is no such thing as the set of all sets, so there can be no Russell's paradox.
Russell was born in 1872 and lived until 1970. So he had plenty of time to digest this resolution his paradox.
I have never learned what Bertrand Russell's reaction to this resolution of his paradox was. I hope some people here can describe it.

Russell proposed his own resolution to the paradox based on Poincare's vicious circle principle that bans definitions where "a collection of objects may contain members which can only be defined by means of the collection as a whole." To implement the principle, Russell developed his ramified theory of types in 1908. It proved to be too cumbersome for doing mathematics, and ZFC used a more practical way to block the paradox. But it was broadly construed as a pragmatic patch, not a serious candidate for its resolution.

@Conifold When you write "it was broadly construed," does "it" refer to the ramified theory of types, or to Zermelo's approach (in ZFC) to avoiding the paradox?

But from the cumbersome "ramified" later logicians developed the modern Type Theory.

The resolution proposed by Whitehead and Russell in the Principia Mathematica is to use ramified type theory. Unlike simple type theory, ramified types involve a hierarchy of properties that are required to be predicative. Russell attributed the problems arising from various paradoxes as being due to the use of impredicative definitions. So the proposed solution requires us to build up the hierarchy by defining first order properties, then defining second order properties which may refer to first order ones, and then third order ones and so on. At each order, definitions can refer only to the orders below them.
This approach proved restrictive and cumbersome and as far as I know few mathematicians are willing to adopt it. In order to avoid enforcing a distinction between predicative and impredicative functions, W&R introduced an axiom of reducibility stating that for any predicate of any order, there is a first order predicate that is equivalent to it. This axiom is highly controversial and difficult to justify, though it has never been proved to be inconsistent.
As you say, the most popular approach is to make use of an axiom system that avoids the construction of sets that are members of themselves.
In ZFC there is no unrestricted axiom of comprehension and no set of all sets.
In NBG there is a proper class of all sets and a proper class containing all sets that are not members of themselves. This does not lead to Russell's paradox because these classes do not contain themselves as elements.
In New Foundations (NF) there is a set of all sets. NF is like an unramified version of Russell's types, though it does retain the concept of a stratified formula. It is a non-well-founded set theory. It does not prove the existence of a Russell set.
Other, less common ways of avoiding Russell's paradox are to accept naive set theory with its unrestricted axiom of comprehension and use a substructural logic without contraction that does not permit the derivation of the paradox. Or if you really want to go off the deep end, you can follow Graham Priest and accept that some contradictions such as Russell's paradox are true, and use a logic that does not explode.

Thanks! I completely forgot about Principia Mathematica (since no one I know has ever looked at it). But after that attempt was not widely accepted, and ZFC was, is there any record of Russell's discussing this matter?

This is all very nice but how does it address the question as asked? As a matter of fact, the OP anticipates at least some of this account, as the snippet "the resolution most often quoted" [namely, ZF] indicates (admitting there might be several resolutions, plural). The question has own little problems but it is quite explicit in what it asks: what was Bertrand Russell's reaction to this resolution [namely ZFC] of his paradox?
